# Spring boot Redirect Login Page error , I want to redirect my client Login page

Tags: spring-boot, oauth-2.0

I want to redirect login page to `127.0.0.1:4200/login` but it redirect to `127.0.0.1:7676/login`

My code given below:

```java
@Configuration
public class AuthorizationConfig {
    @Bean
    @Order(1)
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizationServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer authorizationServerConfigurer = new OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer();
        http.apply(authorizationServerConfigurer);
        OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);

        http
            .getConfigurer(OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfigurer.class)
            .oidc(Customizer.withDefaults());

        http
            .exceptionHandling(exceptions -> exceptions.authenticationEntryPoint(new CustomLoginUrlAuthenticationProcessingFilter("localhost:4200")));

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

And others:

```java
public class CustomLoginUrlAuthenticationProcessingFilter extends AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {
    @Override
    public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authException) throws IOException, ServletException {
        response.sendRedirect(loginUrl);
    }
}
```

This is the my code actually below. So I want to redirect my desired login page. as it a authorization server and using oauth2 and jwt.

I want to solve this

I want to expect to redirect `127.0.0.1:4200/login`